# ImportError: No module named keyboard

Tags: python-3.x, macos

not working

```
import pygame,sys,random,time,keyboard
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
ImportError: No module named keyboard
[dir: /Users/sebastianegeland/Desktop/kode stuff]
[path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Pyt
```

Answer (score 8):

Looks like you simply did not install the 'keyboard' library.
In your terminal simply do

```
pip install keyboard
```

It should work.

For clarity I would do one import per line as well, as follow:

```
import pygame
import sys
import etc
```

This is the preferred way to import multiple modules.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I had Python 3.7 selected as my interpreter in Visual Studio Code. When I changed it to Python 3.8, the import was successful.