# No module named 'keyboard' in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm using windows 10, python 3.9, jupyter notebook(anaconda 3)

```
C:\Users\tmp>pip install keyboard
Requirement already satisfied: keyboard in c:\users\tmp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (0.13.5)
```

```
import keyboard
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-9d28139d8d74> in <module>
      1 import pyautogui as pag
----> 2 import keyboard

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyboard'
```

Comment: If you have more than one python installation, how do you know which one you've installed to, and which one is running Jupyter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57761896/importerror-no-module-named-keyboard)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError on virtual env Jupyter lab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64367671/modulenotfounderror-on-virtual-env-jupyter-lab)

Comment: Solved with installing the module in jupyter notebook. Thank you guys.